# Actionscript 3. Remove loader with a for

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, removechild

I have a loader that I want to remove, and instead of removing one by one

```
removeChild(ImgLoader1);
removeChild(ImgLoader3);
removeChild(ImgLoader4);
removeChild(ImgLoader5);
removeChild(ImgLoader6);
```

I want to remove them with a for loop, like this

```
for(i=1; i<=6; i++) {
  removeChild(ImgLoader[i]);
}
```

but it is not working because it isn't uniting the `ImgLoader[i]` and making `ImgLoader1..2..3`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
//Define a global image loader array where you are going to store the references
var imageLoaders:Array = [];

var imageLoader:ImageLoader = new ImageLoader();
var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://server.com/myimage.gif");
imageLoader.load(image);

//store a reference for later use...
imageLoaders.push(imageLoader);

// add to the stage
addChild(imageLoader);

// and then later to remove the image loaders from the stage
for(var i:int = 0; i < imageLoaders.length; i++) {
  removeChild(imageLoaders[i]);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject. :(

Comment: can you show where you are creating the ImageLoader instances?